# How do I invoke a method on an instance of a class that isn't yet defined?

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, instance

I have a class called Dev, that contains a method called addToTasksAssigned that adds tasks to an ArrayList

```
public void addToTasksAssigned(String newTask){
    tasksAssigned.add(newTask);
}
```

In my task class, I have a method called setAssignedDev. I want this to add the input of this function to the list of tasks assigned in Dev:

```
public void setAssignedDev(String newDev){
    this.assignedDev=newDev;
    newDev.addToTasksAssigned(getProject());  //getProject() here is just the task name    

    }
```

I understand that I cannot call upon a class that doesn't exist yet, which is why the code doesn't work. Is there a way of restricting the 'String newDev' input so that it has to be an instance of the Dev class? Is there no way of referencing instances of classes from other classes?

Thanks

Comment: Yes... Use `public void setAssignedDev(Dev newDev)`

Comment: Why not make the `newDev` parameter a `Dev` type, rather than `String`?

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is quite unclear.  Is it the *class* that somehow doesn't exist yet, or the *instance* of a known class, or are you referring to one of several possible existing classes?  (Keep in mind that you can't create a *class* "out of thin air", it must be defined in a .java source file.)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Dev` class with your registered users:

```
public class Dev {

    private final String name;
    private final List<?> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters / setters / constructors, etc

}
```

And from there, have a class that manages Dev members:

```
public class UserManager {

    private Map<String, Dev> devs = new HashMap<>();

    public void addDev(Dev dev) {
        this.devs.put(dev.getName(), dev);
    }

}
```

You should have these loaded initially and accessible through some form (keeping managers linked through main class, and passing the main class instance is a good way). This will let you pass Dev objects instead and in the future add more functionality to their Objects